# Required switch per building

Tags: networking, switch, infrastructure

Conventions:
- Building: Called building, in fact it is a container (used for shipment 42ftx8ft).

The scenario:
- There are 4 buildings installed on the ground, separated between 32ft(10m) and 49ft(15m) long.
- Each building hast its own cabling structure. Each one has a wall mount rack.
- Each building is expected to be realocated in another ground area, so the unmount and mount of network and structured cabling per building must be quick and clean. Meaning that just a STP cable needs to be unppluged from the ***building switch*** to move the bulding.
- The data center is located at the right most building.

Additional information:
- Network must support voip: so, a layer 2 managed switch 100/1000 is used for vlans

Knowing that a layer 2 managed switch will be located at the data center building (for voip and data vlans), my doubt is wich kind of switch do I need to install per the three buildings? A layer 2 no-managed switch, 100/100 100/1000?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can't think of a reason to ever use an unmanaged switch. Or not have at least gigabit throughput. That would be asking for problems that are easily avoided.

Comment: Without knowing how much bandwidth is required, all we can say is "it depends". But as @GregAskew said, there's no reason to use unmanaged switches. If you do, you're going to be lost trying to troubleshoot problems.

Comment: Also, if these are separate building with different grounds, you should probably be using optical connections, not copper. Check with a local electrician.

Comment: I thought it in the way that the data center building has the managed L2 switch, so the other ones switches will just have to "replicate" the vlans on its ports. I wanted to pass all network cabling coming from the data center switch (BROCADE ICX7150-48-4x1G) throug undeground pipelines (using STP cat 5e), but, due to the further easy realocation of the buildings (unmount and mount of network connection; unplug and plug a network cable that comes from de data center or internet source), I've thinking wich kind of switch to install for each building. @GregAskew

Comment: 512Kbps and QoS for voip using a 20 users basic voip pbx. @mfinni